# How can I use a .NET dll in a web page

Tags: html

I am trying to figure out how to use a .NET dll in a web page.  Can this be done with an ActiveX control?  Or some other way?  The following does not work.

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">alert("Top");</script>

This is a web page.


<object id="SimpleVBObject" classid="C:\IntuitiveDev\Bin\Test.dll#Test.Simple"></object>

<script type="text/vbscript">

MsgBox ("simple before")
SimpleVBObject.Message()
MsgBox ("simple after")

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Only the first message box function is called.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I thought it was clear enough.  Use a .NET dll means access properties and call functions.  Web page means code displayed in a browser.

Comment: I guess I've turned stupid today. What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish? I doubt that your end goal is to call properties and methods of a .NET type from a web page.

Comment: I will answer your question even though it is off topic.  In the future keep in mind it is most helpful to answer the question instead of digressing.  Your off topic queries will do nothing to help anyone else who is having the same issue and find this question in their search results.  To satisfy your curiosity; the end result is to display data from a database to the user giving them the option of editing it.  The application consists of hundreds of tables accessed by hundreds of dlls of which I am only interested in about a dozen.

Comment: Mr. Maher, you may find it instructive to compare the length of time I've been on this site to the length of time _you've_ been on this site when considering questions about which comments are on-topic. ActiveX can of course be used, but only in certain circumstances which you have not addressed. It can only be used in IE, and only if you have control of all the clients. In general, there are better ways of accomplishing what you have stated.

Answer (score 0):

See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7as3z1d(v=vs.90).aspx

```
<object id="myCtl" 
   classid="http://www.mycode.Microsoft.com/mycode.dll#myClass"> 
</object>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It pointed me in a direction.  That works for a server hosted control but not a local control.  For that you need something more like this:
<OBJECT ID="UserControl1" CLASSID="CLSID:9F769412-6736-39DD-9B29-DEF814E32B26" CODEBASE="rotWI_ShopDataMaintenance.dll#-1,-1,-1,-1" height="300" width="300">
But I do not know yet where to get the classid.